# XPATH -> querying object attributes and text data simultaneously?

Tags: xml, xpath

This is xml data i'd like to query

```
<bookstore>

<book category="COOKING">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price dollarValue="1.5">30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="CHILDREN">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price dollarValue="1.5">29.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
  <author>James McGovern</author>
  <author>Per Bothner</author>
  <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
  <author>James Linn</author>
  <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price dollarValue="1.5">49.99</price>
</book>

<book category="WEB">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price dollarValue="1.5">39.95</price>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

I need to extract the "WEB" category `author` text and `dollar` attribute located inside price simultaneously

This was my best query, (not working)

```
//book[@category="WEB"]/*[self::author//text() or self::price/@dollarValue]
```

Which part of this query should i modify to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to query two different things: attribute and text node. The closest thing to accomplish the task in one go might be using 2 XPath queries combined using union operator (`|`) :

```
(//book[@category="WEB"]/author/text() | //book[@category="WEB"]/price/@dollarValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
//book[@category="WEB"]/author/(text()|../price/@dollarValue)
```